# SAS data step error "too long for buffer"

Tags: sas, buffer, datastep

I am just trying to load a SAS file someone else sent. I can open the dataset by just clicking on it and I can run `proc contents`. However, when I tried to copy the data to the work library, or run some summary statistics, this error message occurred:

> ERROR: An internal error has occurred while reading a compressed file.
>   Please call your SAS Site Representative and report the
>          following: compress offset = 330 , de-compress offset = 320 , compress buf = "" .
>
> ERROR: Record in file lib1.file_name.DATA is too
>   long for buffer.

I tried to increase the bufsize `options bufsize=32768` or use 
`compress = Yes`, but neither helped. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this is talking about the decompression algorithm (unrelated to the buffer that BUFSIZE is talking about).  It sounds like it got corrupted; you may want to contact the source of the dataset and ask for a new copy (perhaps one uncompressed).  But really more a question for SAS Tech Support.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your dataset is damaged. 
So you can try to repair with **proc datasets** and this statement : **repair**

Here an example :

```
PROC DATASETS LIB = WORK;
REPAIR JUNESALES;
QUIT;

source : 
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/070-2007.pdf
```

Otherwise you have to get a new file of your dataset (if you have a backup it could be useful).

Regards,